# Custom Graph with datetime and custom interval

Tags: c#, forms, plot, charts

I want to create a custom bar chart using Chart tooling from Windows.Forms.
I want to show only the beginning and end of the series data. I also want to plot the left axis (AxisY) as strings. (see picture below)

[image]

So far,

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.NotSet;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;
```

However this code will show all thicks that I do not want to see. How to hide them and show the ticks only at the beginning and end.

Comment: 1) the left axis is the x-axis for a bar chart. 2) is what you show what you have or what you want? ticks are not gridlines; both can be shown at intervals of their own as can the labels. none are shown only at datapoint values but always at regular intervals.

Comment: Thank you @TaW for clarification. This is what I want, not what I show currently.